# How can I set/remove element's parent on gripup/gripdown Vive controller events in A-Frame?

Tags: javascript, parent-child, aframe, htc-vive

Using the Vive controllers, I want to be able to trigger-click-and-hold on an object in my A-Frame scene, and be able to then move and rotate that object in the space of the VR scene, by moving the controller in space.

One way I can think of doing this is: on trigger pull, to make the object a child of the controller, so it inherits position and rotation from the controller.

In Three.js, I could use:

`THREE.SceneUtils.detach( child, parent, scene );
THREE.SceneUtils.attach( child, scene, parent )`;

How can I set/remove parent on gripup/gripdown events in A-Frame?

Answer (score 0):

One of the A-Frame examples does what you describe, actually.

Here's the scene [index.html](https://github.com/aframevr/aframe/blob/master/examples/showcase/tracked-controls/index.html), [`grab` component](https://github.com/aframevr/aframe/blob/master/examples/showcase/tracked-controls/components/grab.js), and a [demo](https://aframe.io/examples/showcase/tracked-controllers/).